# Playing sounds simultaneously on iOS devices

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer

I have 10 sounds in one view. And they all play, however only one sound can play at a time. I want it so you can tap the sounds you want to play, and they all play at the same time. But at the moment when you press a sound it plays, then you go to press another sound and the sound previously stops.

Here is the code which I have used for the sounds

```
- (IBAction)oneSound:(id)sender; {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"wav"];
    if (theAudio) [theAudio release];
    NSError *error = nil;
    theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];   


}



- (IBAction)twoSound:(id)sender; {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"2" ofType:@"wav"];
    if (theAudio) [theAudio release];
    NSError *error = nil;
    theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];   

}



- (IBAction)threeSound:(id)sender; {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3" ofType:@"wav"];
    if (theAudio) [theAudio release];
    NSError *error = nil;
    theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];   

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This probably causes the problem:

```
if (theAudio) [theAudio release];
```

The AVAudioPlayer cannot continue playing after it's released.

What basically happens:
- Button click
- theAudio is initialized
- theAudio starts playing
- Another button click
- theAudio is released and therefor stops playing
- theAudio is initialized with another sound
- theAudio starts playing

Comment: No, simply create `oneAudio`,`twoAudio` and `threeAudio` instead of only `theAudio` in the header file. Now you can play `oneAudio` with `- (IBAction)oneSound:(id)sender` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your theAudio is global and you instantiate it again in each method. Transform it in a local variable or define 3 (or how many you need).